# loop over results from logistic regression and put them in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, logistic-regression

I have an issue with looping over results of three logistic regression analyses.  I am trying to put the exp(b)/odds ratio and their 95% confidence intervals into a data frame, side-by-side.  I would like to have the model name (e.g., model 1, model 2, and model 3) in the columns and the variables on the rows.  I have been trying to modify code I have found from this site--(I thought I would check here before I would post my question, but nothing is spot on, but if I missed it please point me in that direction).  Unfortunately, this appears to be a bit above my knowledge base.  This is the code that I am trying to use.  It does the base calculations, and creates a tibble with just the coefficients, but I need the exp(b)/odds ratio and the CIs for each model as I said with the model name in the columns, and the variables in the rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

forms <- list(model1 = admit ~ gre, model2 = admit ~ gre + gpa, model3 = admit ~ gre + gpa + rank)

map_df(forms, ~coef(glm(.x, mydata, family = "binomial"))) %>%
  select(-1)
```

How would I modify the script to collect the information I need, and in the data frame style my study will need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`broom::tidy()` is very handy for these problems. Try

```r
m1 <- (forms
   |> map(glm, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
   |> map_dfr(broom::tidy, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE, .id = "model")
)
print(m1)
```

`select()` and `pivot_wider()` are useful for converting, e.g.

```r
(m1 
   |> dplyr::select(model, term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high) 
   |> pivot_wider(names_from = "term",
                  values_from = c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high"))
)
```

Comment: This is about 85% where I need it to be.  How would I tell the script to, also, give the 95% confidence interval?

Comment: see edits (also includes reshaping the results)

Comment: Now that I can see the rest of your code, I have applied the m1 portion.  It is not working for some reason.  Here is the error that I am getting: "Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"  What may be causing this?

Comment: you have the MASS package loaded. Use `dplyr::select` to specify which version of `select` you want.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening, but I tried using the dplyr::select and I tried loading the library dplyr--separately.  Neither worked.  I can see where this has promise, so I would like to stick with it.  I am not sure why this still happening.  Is there a work around or a different method?

Comment: loading `dplyr` again won't necessarily help.  If you run your code, then mine, in a **clean** R session, does it work? If not, post results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: I got it!  It worked.  Thank you for solving this problem.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...